# Сохранение пароля браузером при Ajax авторизации

Tags: ajax, авторизация, пароль

Добрый день. Так получилось, что авторизация у меня происходит так:
Пользователь вводит данные, и при нажатии кнопки "вход" информация обрабатывается через ajax-запрос. При удачном логине страница просто обновляется.
При таком подходе браузер не запоминает пароли(я имею в виду эти окошечки "сохранить пароль?").. А я хочу, чтоб сохранял, функция-то удобная.
Какие бы костыли сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я задавал такой же [вопрос на Хабре](https://toster.ru/q/17679/) и получил отличный ответ:

```
1. Сделайте себе фейковый адрес который ничего не делает и возвращает 200 ответ
2. Форме укажите этот фейковый адрес и _target=«iframe_name» (естественно фрейм должен быть)
2. Перед аяксовой отправкой данных на правильный адрес, делайте реальный сабмит формы.
3. Логиньтесь аяксом, смотрите как браузер спрашивает не запомнить ли логин/пароль
4.!!!
5. PROFIT!
```

Comment: Да, это лучший ответ. Хотя также стоит отметить ответ @Zhukov_Roman.
Единственное, что я обнаружил методом тыка, и что, я надеюсь, поможет кому-нибудь в трудную минуту:  
1) в форме одно поле обязательно должно быть type=password  
2) у всех полей не должно быть предустановленное значение (value="")

Answer (score 2):

Только с использованием iframe ([пример](https://gist.github.com/kostiklv/968927)). Потому что в AJAX-форме вы отменяете действие submit и посылаете ajax-запрос. А браузер запоминает данные только при успешной отправке формы классическим методом.

Answer (score 1):

Можна пошаманить вот так:

```
<form id="loginform" action="login.php" onSubmit="return login(this);">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" value="" required="required" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" value="" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" name="doLogin" value="Login" />
</form>
```

JS код:

```
function login(f) {
    var username = f.username.value;
    var password = f.password.value;

    //ajax magic here
    return false; //or the form will post your data to login.php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Часто хватает галочки «запомнить меня». Хранить пароли — это неправильно. Пользователей нужно отучать от этого.

Comment: Галочка есть..  
Я согласен с тем, что если хранить пароли, то люди их забывают, и потом, если случайно они сотрутся из памяти браузера, то не могут их вспомнить...  
Но тем не менее, будут воротить нос, если пароли не будут сохраняться.

Comment: Если пароли не будут сохраняться, будет сложнее взломать аккаунт. А вообще я что-то сомневаюсь, что это поведение браузера можно контролировать. А почему именно ajax? Почему не обычным POST запросом?